# How to prevent update anomalies with multiple clients running non-atomic computations concurrently in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, concurrentmodification

I am running three PostgreSQL instances using replication (1 master, 2 slaves) which are accessed by two separate servers:

- The first (unexposed) server basically iterates over every row in a particular table and continuously updates specific columns (resources) every tick (based on production rate of those resources) for each user.
- The second server is a public API that exposes various functions such as spending a certain amount of those resources.

In order to access and manipulate the data I am using an ORM library which allows me to write code as follows:

```js
const resources = await repository.findById(1337);
// some complex computation
resources.iron = computeNewIron(resources.iron);
await repository.save(resources);
```

Of course it might occur that the API wants to deduct a specific amount of resources right when the server handling the ticks is trying to update the amount of resources which can cause either of the servers to assume a certain amount of resources that is incorrect, basically your typical UPDATE anomaly.

My problem is that I am not just writing a "simple" atomic query such `UPDATE table SET iron = iron + 42 WHERE id = :id`. The ORM library is internally using a direct assignment that is not self-referencing the respective columns which yields something akin to `UPDATE table SET iron = 123 WHERE id = :id` where the amount has been computed previously.

I can just assume that it's possible to prevent the mentioned anomaly if I use manually written queries that are incrementing/decrementing the values atomically with self-references. I'd like to know which other options can alleviate the issue. Should I wrap my SELECT/computation/UPDATE in a transaction? Does this suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if your transaction spans several statements, yet needs to have a consistent state of the database, there are basically two options:

1. Use pessimistic locking: when you read values from the database, do it with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. Then the rows are locked for the duration of your transaction, and no concurrent transaction can modify them.
2. Use optimistic locking: start your transaction in `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level. Then you see a consistent snapshot of the database for the whole duration of your transaction. If somebody else modifies your data after you read them, your `UPDATE` will cause a *serialization error* and you'll have to retry the transaction.

Optimistic locking is better if conflicts are rare, while pessimistic locking is preferable if conflicts are likely.